# How to make Midnight Commander remembers Shell Link address/name?

Tags: mc

Using Shell link function, Midnight Commander usually remembers machine name that we have enter in the past, and we can access them by clicking a tick at the right of machine's name field. But the last time I install MC, it can't store the machine's name.

How can I configure in order to have shell link remembers the machine name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think you are talking about a bookmarks?
if you already did a login one successful, then Shell link prompt keep it for next use, it is greylight when you get to Shell link again.
If you want to bookmarking your links to different servers, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> hotkey
There you can bookmark and edit your links

If any problems with saving it to use it again, then need to check access permissions for mc configuration files.
Maybe your env at console not allow you to rewrite and you do not have a change when restarting mc.
By default it keeps files in user home folder:

```
~/.config/mc
~/.local/share/mc
~/.mc.menu
```

I think in your situation the issue can be solved through permissions to write for `~/.local/share/mc/history`.
It keeps everything you typing and listing before.